# How to reuse Android XML layouts with minor differences?

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say i have the Android XML file `home_page.xml`.

on this `home_page.xml` i have some variations that i want to show at different activities, and i'd like to reuse the same main layout `home_page.xml`.

For example, imagine variations on the page such as:

1. there's 2 more buttons if the user is in state A
2. there's 1 more editText field if the user is in state B (same activity as state A)
3. there's a different arrangement of layout on the Z-axis in a frame layout if the user is in state C (same activity as state A)

i know it's possible to programmatically say hide views and set views as visible. but is there a better way to do this via xml or something?

Comment: Would "state A" and "state B" be different `Activities`? If so, you could use the `<include>` tag to include the `home_page.xml` in those `layout`s then each of those have the `View`s they need.

Comment: I would just make 3 different layouts. Will be much easier to maintain in the future if you want to add/remove stuff. If you start using setVisibility ever where it can become a mess.

Comment: @codeMagic good clarification. suppose same activity

Comment: If we are supposing the same `Activity` then I would just use one `layout` and hide/show `View`s when needed (using multiple `layout`s in one `Activity` is rarely a good idea). However, if you are doing a lot of hiding/showing then I would rethink your design and split it up into different `Activities` and/or use `Fragment`s. And you still have the `<include>` if much of the `layout` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Android recommends using 2 Tags for re-using the layouts across different screens.

- Include

**When to Use ?** 
If you already know the layout that you want to re-use, create a new XML file and define the layout. Use  tag to re-use it.

- Merge

**When to Use ?**

To eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another, we can use  tag.

Refer to this link - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html for code sample and more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide views but using the [Visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) flag.

```
View v = findViewById(R.Id.my_view);
v.setVisiblity(View.GONE); //etc.
```

I've tried stuff like this before. I had mixed results. This is fine if you are doing things, like asking the user for a name, then showing an address input or something. But if you find yourself with like 3 or 4 conditions for one editText and then different ones for a button in the same class you might want to just use different layouts. A lot easier to manage.